# Spring : use multithreading to perform a long task

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot

In a Spring REST application, I want to save 100 000 elements in my database from an external API, which returns XML answer.
I can do it using multiple threads since I am able to retrieve a range of these elements (ex: 1-1000, 1001-2000) when doing a GET request to this external API.

One thread retrieves a range from a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. If this range is not null, this thread download elements. If not, it ends.

If I had 8000 elements to retrieve and wanted to do this task with 4 threads, I'd had this situation :
[Multithreading task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYStA.png)

I know I can do it using a derived class from Thread, but **is there a proper way to use multithreading to achieve a long task in Spring Boot ?**

I tried with `CompletableFuture` but I don't know how to configure the number of threads with it.

In advance, many thanks for your answers !

Comment: You might want to check [TaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I finally found this excellent tutorial (doable with spring): [Tutorial from Calli Coder](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/)

You can therefore use `TaskExecutor` (as suggested by mckszcz) along with `CompletableFuture` to perform a long task :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Controller:
    @PostMapping("/processDeUpload/{userid}")
    public DeferredResult<List<String>> processDataToDeUpload(@PathVariable("userid") String userid,
            @RequestBody DeUploadReqDTO deUploadReqDTO) {
        DeferredResult<List<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(99990000L, "Timed out");
//      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dEUploadService.processMultiJrnlToDe(userid, deUploadReqDTO))
//              .whenCompleteAsync((result, throwable) -> deferredResult.setResult(result));

        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dEUploadService.processSingleJrnlToDe(userid, deUploadReqDTO))
                .whenCompleteAsync((result, throwable) -> deferredResult.setResult(result));
        return deferredResult;
    }



    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool((list.size() / 100) < 30 ? (list.size() / 100) + 1 : 30);
            java.util.List<Future<String>> futuresList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
            List<List<CREATESINGLEJRNLFSFSREQ>> lists = Lists.partition(list, 100);
            for (List<CREATESINGLEJRNLFSFSREQ> temp : lists) {
                Future<String> futureObject = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        Iterator<CREATESINGLEJRNLFSFSREQ> iterator = temp.iterator();
                        String errorMsg = null;
                        ERRORType errorTypeSigle = null;
                        StatusKey key = null;
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            String soapXml;
                            String response = null;
                            boolean isRefValid = false;
                            String batchNo = null;
                            Integer currNo = null;
                            CREATESINGLEJRNLFSFSREQ singleReq = iterator.next();
                            soapXml = convertSoap.convertFlexRequestObjectToXmlString(singleReq).substring(55);
                            StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer().append(header).append(soapXml).append(footer);
                            try {

                                try {
                                    batchNo = singleReq.getFCUBSBODY().getJrnlLogFull().getBATCHNO();
                                    currNo = singleReq.getFCUBSBODY().getJrnlLogFull().getCURRNO().intValue();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    LOGGER.error("batch " + batchNo + " currNo " + currNo);
                                }
                                LOGGER.info(batchStr + batchNo + currStr + currNo);
                                if (!activeProfile.equalsIgnoreCase(noProfile)) {
                                    response = soapHttpsClient.httpsRequest(request.toString(), deUrl,
                                            "CreateSingleJrnlFS");
                                } else {
                                    response = EMPTY;
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                errorTypeSigle = null;
                                LOGGER.error("Exception in request processing  ", e);
                            }
                            LOGGER.error("Error Message/Code : " + errorTypeSigle);
                            LOGGER.error("Error Message/Code : " + errorTypeSigleList);

                            key = new StatusKey(batchNo, currNo);

                            /***/
                            if (response.contains("<MSGSTAT>SUCCESS</MSGSTAT>")) {
                                LOGGER.info("--------------------DE SUCCESS---------------------");
                                // isRefValid = refNumberCheck(resp.getFCUBSBODY().getJrnlLogFull());

                                isRefValid = refNumberCheck(response, singleReq.getFCUBSHEADER().getBRANCH());
                                LOGGER.info("--isRefValid---" + isRefValid);
                                if (isRefValid)
                                    statusMap.put(key, "S");
                                else
                                    statusMap.put(key, refCheckStr);
                            } else if (response.contains("<MSGSTAT>FAILURE</MSGSTAT>")) {
                                LOGGER.info("--------------------DE FAILURE---------------------");

                                errorMsg = response.substring(response.indexOf("<FCUBS_ERROR_RESP>") + 18,
                                        response.indexOf("</FCUBS_ERROR_RESP>"));
                                String errorCode = errorMsg.substring(errorMsg.indexOf("<ECODE>") + 7,
                                        errorMsg.indexOf("</ECODE>"));
                                String errorDesc = errorMsg.substring(errorMsg.indexOf("<EDESC>") + 7,
                                        errorMsg.indexOf("</EDESC>"));
                                LOGGER.info("Failure Msg Error------- " + errorCode + errorDesc + errorMsg);

                                statusMap.put(key, errorCode + errorDesc);
                            } else {
                                LOGGER.info("--------------------DE EMPTY/NULL RES---------------------");
                                statusMap.put(key, "Empty/Null Response From Flex");
                            }
                        }
                        return EMPTY;
                    }
                });
                futuresList.add(futureObject);
            }

            for (Future<String> eachFuture : futuresList) {
                try {
                    eachFuture.get(60L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("thread interuptted" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("execution exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("TimeoutException " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    LOGGER.error("Could not execute the statment in 20 mins");
                    throw new InternalServerException("Request timeout for the request " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                    throw new InternalServerException("Exception occoured " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            executorService.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(Constants.EXCEPTION_LOG, e);
            statusMap.put(new StatusKey(deUploadReqDTO.getPendingForAuthDTO().getBatchNumber(), -1), e.toString());
        } finally {
            updateStatus(deUploadReqDTO, userid, deUploadReqDTO.getPendingForAuthDTO().getBatchNumber());

        }
        List<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        return ll;
    }

}
```